# How do I change the buttons in the Kendo ListBox toolbar

Tags: kendo-ui

I created a dual kendo listboxs to move items between each other.  In horizontal layout the buttons look fine and correct.  But I in my vertical pairing the buttons that point left and right do not work.

What I would like to be able to do or get information on is how to modify each button individually but not have to change the core functionality of the button.  I still want the transferTo and transferFrom to work as normal but I would like the button to look different (or have words maybe).

```
            var availableUsers = $("#usersavailable").kendoListBox({
            connectWith: "selectedusers",
            draggable: true,
            dataTextField: "UserName",
            dataValueField: "UserId",
            selectable: "multiple",
            dataSource: [],
            toolbar: {
                position: "bottom",
                tools: [
                    {
                        type: "splitButton", text: 'Insert Down', icon: 'insert-down'}
                    },
                    //"transferTo",
                    "transferFrom",
                    "transferAllTo",
                    "transferAllFrom"],


            },
        }).data("kendoListBox");
        var selectedUsers = $("#selectedusers").kendoListBox({
            dataTextField: "UserName",
            dataValueField: "UserId",
            draggable: true,
            selectable: "multiple",
            dataSource: [],
            remove: function (e) {
                setSelected(e, false);
            },
            add: function (e) {
                setSelected(e, true);
            }
        }).data("kendoListBox");
```

Ideally the page in the documentation that directly talks about how to use this would be great.  Trying to find out something specific about what to put where and what it means has been a challenge to find.

Comment: Have you tried to set the messages per button, as documented on https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/listbox/configuration/messages?

Comment: @CarstenFranke I looked up that link and it does not seem to do anything.  The button is still the same.  It does not change the text or the button.  I would like to be able to modify the "tool" look but the functionality.  The API example rewrites the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `messages` configuration property lets you set the text for a command button, which gets rendered as the `title` of the command element.  The browser pops up it's default title tooltip on button hover.

I'm not sure if you can specify a toolbar splitButton in the Listbox configuration.

Select the buttons to use with `toolbar.tools` and the message text for each with `messages.tools`

From [Listbox Configuration messages docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/listbox/configuration/messages#messagestools)

> ```
> $("#listBoxA").kendoListBox({
>     connectWith: "listBoxB",
>     dataSource: [ "ItemA1", "ItemA2" ],
>     toolbar: {
>         tools: [ "moveUp", "moveDown", "remove",
>                  "transferTo", "transferFrom", "transferAllTo", "transferAllFrom" ]
>     },
>     messages: {
>         tools: {
>             moveUp: "my MoveUp message",
>             moveDown: "my MoveDown message",
>             remove: "Remove",
>             transferTo: "my TransferTo message",
>             transferFrom: "my TransferFrom message",
>             transferAllTo: "my TransferAllTo message",
>             transferAllFrom: "my TransferAllFrom message"
>         }
>     }
> ```

You can change your ListBox icons with some jQuery that alters the element corresponding to the command icon:

```
$(".k-listbox-toolbar [data-command='transferAllTo'] span").attr("class", "k-icon k-i-warning");
```

If you also want actual text after the toolbar icon, override the icon's width and `after()` the text:

```
-- css --
.k-listbox-toolbar [data-command="transferAllTo"] { width: auto; }

-- js --
$(".k-listbox-toolbar [data-command='transferAllTo'] span")
.attr("class", "k-icon k-i-warning")
.after("Hi")
;
```

See dojo [Tweaked ListBox ToolBar](https://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/EBUFoLIw)